# How to insert a dot under a letter in microsoft word in mac?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I know we can insert dot over the letter using \dot in equation (math). But how do we insert something like this: ṇ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This is done on Windows (might work on Mac, not certain)

1. Type `0323`, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for the dot symbol to appear below the character placeholder.
2. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>, to show the character placeholder, type your character.

[image]

Comment: That looks a very "windowsy" way to do something. Is that really also true for Mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes it's "windowsy"  using Unicode to enter the dot below the character. I will update the answer with tha important point.

Comment: I've not known anything on Mac use that 'alt codes' method at all (though I hardly ever use Word, so I honestly don't know if they've ported it specially for Office apps). Many things on Office Mac are quite non-Mac-like. Normally to add a combining diacritical (one that's not easily available from the keyboard) you find it in Character Viewer & just double-click it.

Comment: @Tetsujin It is a shame that you don't use the app so much. Your suggestion for character viewer is good one that if tested could help the OP.

Comment: As you all have said, that method doesn’t work on Mac Word ... I tried. But the suggestion for the Character Viewer is spot on. Use the Latin Group of characters.

Comment: @Tetsujin Post the character viewer suggestion as an answer. I will be upvoting it.

Comment: Yes, that's Windowsy. The Mac equivalent is to type the n, and then hold down the Option key and type in the Unicode reference (0323). For this to work, you have to be using the Unicode Hex Reference input source (System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources tab; or depending on how your Mac is set up, the Input Source menu might appear in the menu bar, or you might be able to press Command+Spacebar to switch between input sources). I don't know whether this works in the desktop version of Word; but it definitely works in Word online when accessed on a Mac.

Comment: @cnread Thanks for the input. Good to know that what you described work for Word online.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac the only way I know to do this is with the Character View of Apple and use it to insert the **ṇ** letter.

To enable the Character View pane go to System Preferences > Keyboard and check the box for Showing the Keyboard and Emoji Viewers on the Menu Bar.

With that set on your Menu Bar you can select the Emoji and Symbols > Latin item from the menu and insert the necessary character by double clicking on it. You can also set this character as a Favorite so you can reduce the number of clicks to find and insert it.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But if @Tesujin also answer, I possible that I will retract it as he was the first to suggest the character viewer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I concur. I just wanted to make sure an answer was listed for future viewers of this thread. For me, it’s not about points and badges.

Comment: Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I'm quite happy for someone else to answer -  it's based on a suggestion I cannot easily test anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm using the equation in the word on mac, I can insert middle dot by pressing option+8. Hope this helps.